# Verifying consistancy constraints Mysql

Tags: mysql, constraints

How to check the following consistancy in a table?

table goes like this:

```
Employee:

employee_id | Name | job_title | department_name
```

> ***All employees that have the same job title must belong to the same department.***
>
> For example: All employees that work as Stock Managers belongs to a
>   department Shipping. If any of the employees work in the other
>   department with the same job title, the script must display the
>   violations of the consistency constraint defined above in the
>   following format.

JOB TITLE | EMPLOYEE ID | DEPARTMENT NAME

Comment: And where/how did you define that `stock manager` should belong to `shipping`?

Comment: Thank you for your response.It is not defined but for this task, we are to assume that stock managers belong to shipping department.

Comment: `assume` doesn't really work while coding. What about other departments? If you need output as you expect, you need to have a master source or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely possible with `CONSTRAINTS` alone, because you still need to be dependent on data that is not stored anywhere. This can be achieved by having another lookup table that just talks about the relationship between `JOB_TITLE` and `DEPARTMENT`.

Until and unless that relationship is not achieved, this requirement might not work as you expect.

The following should do what you expect:

```
CREATE TABLE JOB_DEPT_RELATIONSHIP AS (
    JOB_TITLE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DEPARTMENT VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(JOB_TITLE, DEPARTMENT)
);
```

Then your actual table can be defined as like this, I guess:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE AS (
    EMPLOYEE_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    JOB_TITLE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_JOB_DEPT_RELATIONSHIP FOREIGN KEY (JOB_TITLE, DEPARTMENT_NAME) REFERENCES JOB_DEPT_RELATIONSHIP(JOB_TITLE, DEPARTMENT)
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Surely, the unique key on your job_dept_relationship table just says that the combination of title and department is unique, this won't stop having the same title in different departments.

Comment: @NigelRen, it needs to be enhanced. What I suggested was an approximate solution (based on OP's assumption).

Answer (score 0):

I believe we may have been given the same task while attending the same University. I am up to this now, these tables might help others see. I am still getting used to the formatting on here.

I am not allowed to post images so I will try sending a link instead, maybe a proper user can edit this for me, thanks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcomv.jpg